WiX Installer - new components added to existing MSI failing to install as part of upgrade
I have an existing MSI but when I add a new file component & feature it doesn't install as part of an UPGRADE. When installed as a first install everything is installed correctly -  What am I missing?
In a nutshell newly added files in components are not installing as part of an upgrade, though they ARE installed fine for a new installation.
I've previously
a) simply added the new file element to the existing component
b) created a new component in the existing feature, and finally / currently
c) Adding a new feature & component for the new file element as per the below snippet, but neither is working.
  <Component Id="cmpNewtonSoft" Guid="565D8C7F-75B9-427B-AD6A-0E10F0B16FC5">
    <File Source="..\..\External References\Newtonsoft.json\13.0.1\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"/>
  </Component>

  <Feature Id="fNewtonSoft" Level="1">
    <ComponentRef Id="cmpNewtonSoft"/>
  </Feature>

</Fragment>

NB WiX 3.14 using the Wix Toolset Visual Studio extension

Looks like you have violated the minor upgrade rules by adding a new non-nested feature. Defining the feature fNewtonSoft as a Child of an existing feature of your setup should fix your issue.
Rob Mensching
MSDN

Thanks for the info - TBH I was unaware of the child rule - every day is a school day. Unfortunately I had already simply tried to add the new file element to the existing component, and only when this failed did I create a new feature. I've updated the question to reflect this.
